# Set property of a button in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, angular, dom

I have a set of Buttons implemented in HTML, which are shown by the click on another Button:

```
<button
  type="button"
  class="button_searchtype"
  (click)="button_ABCD_tapped()"
  id="button_ABCD">
  ABCD
</button>

<div *ngIf="is_ABCD" class="ABCD">
        <h3>Choose a letter</h3>
        <button class="ABCD_Buttons" (click)="myFunction('A')" id="ABCD_Buttons_A">A</button>
        <button class="ABCD_Buttons" (click)="myFunction('B')" id="ABCD_Buttons_B">B</button>
        <button class="ABCD_Buttons" (click)="myFunction('C')" id="ABCD_Buttons_C">C</button>
        <button class="ABCD_Buttons" (click)="myFunction('D')" id="ABCD_Buttons_D">D</button>
<\div>
```

And the Function

```
button_ABCD_tapped(){
    this.is_ABCD = true;
}
```

Now, I want to define some properties of the buttons depending on different choices, like `color`, and `active`. Therefore, I expanded to function to:

```
button_ABCD_tapped(){
    this.is_ABCD = true;
    document.getElementById("ABCD_Buttons_D").style.background = "#6E6E6E";
    document.getElementById("ABCD_Buttons_D").style.background = "#6E6E6E";
    document.getElementById("ABCD_Buttons_D").style.background = "#E6E6E6";
    document.getElementById("ABCD_Buttons_D").style.background = "#6E6E6E";
}
```

But then, I receive the following error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null

How can i initiate the Element before  calling the function, so that the Element can be found?

Comment: You'd usually use angular when using angular. All the document.getElementById is the exact counter of how you would do this

Comment: I'd recommend against using DOM functions like this. Use Angular where you can. Add a `style.background` directive on the button in the HTML template

Comment: can you show me a example of how to do this? im pretty off the track right now..

Comment: i only change (click)="button_ABCD_tapped()" to  onclick="button_ABCD_tapped()" and its working for me

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-playground-vzzcs3?file=app/hello-framework/hello-framework.component.html Look at the stackblitz demo, just extend it for the other buttons... Also this answer by @user184994  here is correct https://stackoverflow.com/a/52126913/3993662

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `click` function, set the color you want into a variable:

```
this.buttonColor = "#6E6E6E"
```

In your HTML, you can bind to that color like so:

```
  <button class="ABCD_Buttons" [style.background]="buttonColor">D</button>
```

This way, you don't need to deal with the DOM

Answer (score 0):

you can use ngClass instead,forexample

```html
  <button class="ABCD_Buttons" *ngIf="is_ABCD" [ngStyle]="{'background':is_ABCD? '#6E6E6E' : 'red' } (click)="myFunction('D')" id="ABCD_Buttons_D">D</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues with your code.

1. The buttons won't be available right after you set the div's visibility to true. You'll have to check that inside `ngAfterViewChecked` lifecycle hook handler.
2. You shouldn't be directly accessing the DOM using `document.getElementById` as it is considered as an anti-pattern. You should be using `Renderer2` instead.
3. The end tag of your `div` is `<\div>`. When it should have been `</div>`

Keeping both these solutions in mind, here's what I would suggest:

```
import { Component, ViewChild, ElementRef, Renderer2 } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {

  is_ABCD;

  @ViewChild('ABCD_Buttons_A') buttonA: ElementRef;
  @ViewChild('ABCD_Buttons_B') buttonB: ElementRef;
  @ViewChild('ABCD_Buttons_C') buttonC: ElementRef;
  @ViewChild('ABCD_Buttons_D') buttonD: ElementRef;

  constructor(private renderer: Renderer2) {}

  button_ABCD_tapped(){
    this.is_ABCD = true;
  }

  ngAfterViewChecked() {
    this.buttonA && this.renderer.setStyle(this.buttonA.nativeElement, 'background', 'red');
  }

  myFunction() {

  }

}
```

And template

```
<button
  type="button"
  class="button_searchtype"
  (click)="button_ABCD_tapped()"
  id="button_ABCD">
  ABCD
</button>

<div *ngIf="is_ABCD" class="ABCD">
        <h3>Choose a letter</h3>
        <button class="ABCD_Buttons" (click)="myFunction('A')" #ABCD_Buttons_A>A</button>
        <button class="ABCD_Buttons" (click)="myFunction('B')" #ABCD_Buttons_B>B</button>
        <button class="ABCD_Buttons" (click)="myFunction('C')" #ABCD_Buttons_C>C</button>
        <button class="ABCD_Buttons" (click)="myFunction('D')" #ABCD_Buttons_D>D</button>
</div>
```

[Sample StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-udjebx?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html).

Answer (score -2):

Give a `setTimeout` of 0, this will cause the angular change detection to run immediately and in the change detection your DOM element will get rendered.

```
button_ABCD_tapped(){ 
    this.is_ABCD = true;
    setTimeout(() => {
        document.getElementById("ABCD_Buttons_A").style.background = "#6E6E6E";
        document.getElementById("ABCD_Buttons_B").style.background = "#6E6E6E";
        document.getElementById("ABCD_Buttons_C").style.background = "#E6E6E6";
        document.getElementById("ABCD_Buttons_D").style.background = "#6E6E6E";
    }, 0)        
}
```

See this example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yejpkw?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: @RohitSharma: It doesn't depend upon the `interval` we are providing, its the setTimeout which will make the change detection compulsory..